# Laravel "Echo is not defined" when not run on server from command "php artisan serve"

Tags: php, laravel

My laravel application now running on Apache , 
I deployed it by copy 'public' folder from laravel project folder and paste in htdocs inside apache root folder.

Everything work fine.

I am implementing Echo by following this https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/broadcasting#installing-laravel-echo

There is not error and work perfectly when testing on serve from command

`php artisan serve`

(On port 8000)

But when i access file form port 80 it show this error on browser's console
(I haven't change anything)

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Echo is not defined

Here is the containing error file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>Clean Gem Service</title>

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.js') }}"></script>    

</head>
<body>

<div id="app-notification"></div>

<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
<script>
    Echo.private('NewOrderChannel')
        .listen('NewOrderEvent', (e) => {
            console.log(e);
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

How this happened?
Am i deployed my app in wrong way? And how to fix it

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make Echo available?

"Once Echo is installed, you are ready to create a fresh Echo instance in your application's JavaScript. A great place to do this is at the bottom of the resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js file that is included with the Laravel framework"

(https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/broadcasting#installing-laravel-echo)

If so, it looks like you need to use `window.Echo`

Comment: If because of this , why it works when i run on server from command 'php artisan serve' ?

Comment: Because it's a different environment designed for easy prototyping that likely involves automatic loading not present in the other config? Get it up and go to the console in Chrome. Type Echo and see what it returns. Type window.Echo and see what it returns. The  - import Echo from "laravel-echo" - bit seems likely important for a real setup.

Comment: I have tried, type 'window.Echo' on console show 'undefined' on page that opening on port 80
but on port 8000, both 'Echo' and 'window.Echo' work fine.

Comment: Try the modifications to bootstrap.js ... I suspect extra stuff is being loaded in the dev server launched by artisan serve

Comment: One more thing , when i remove `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">` from file above , Browser's console on port 8000 show error 'CSRF token not found', but on port 80 don't show anything about it.

Comment: Well, you should leave that in there. It's useful for request validation. It's proof the requests originated from a page generated by the system. Did the bootstrap.js changes resolve your issue?

Comment: But if add console.log("Hello") inside <script> tag on above file. It show the word "Hello" on browser's console for both port 80 and 8000. So, It look like bootstrap.js isn't loaded when not start serve with _php artisan serve_ command.

Comment: Look like changing bootstrap.js don't make any effect on port 80.

Comment: Thank you so much, After i restart server (Window server 2012) it work fine now. I feel like the world has some mystery. @sorak

Comment: I'm glad your problem is resolved. If you feel that I helped you, please accept my answer. Enjoy Laravel!